# Retrieve session information from request inside an actor?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

so I'm new to scala, play, and akka.

I have a Play endpoint that has an Action. That action send the incoming json to Actor1 which parses and validates the json, and then sends the parsed json object to Actor2 to do some work  with the data. This could keep going, maybe Actor2 sends messages to Actor3 or maybe even Actor4. The problem is, when I'm inside these actors, I need a way to get information from the session, like the userId.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Does play manage the request context that these are being run in inside the actors so that I can somehow retrieve session information from inside the actors without having to pass it through each message?
2. Play manages some sort of context for the request while passing messages into actors right? If I'm not mistaken they do this for database transactions, so that all database operations you do even in separate threads are performed in the same database transaction, and then committed upon sending a response. Could I possibly attach session information to this context as well?
3. Could I use scala implicits to pass this around in a way that is clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No.  Play is a stateless web framework, if you want to get anything from the request, you'll have to include it in the message passed to the actor.
2. Play doesn't handle transactions automatically, nor can you use a transaction across multiple actors.
3. Yes, you could, but for this use case I really don't see the need for actors.

Comment: I saw a presentation on play and it mentioned that play actions were run in an event loop, and that event loop shouldn't be blocked. What is a good use case for actors if not this?

Comment: The scala documentation says: "Because of the way Play 2.0 works, the action code must be as fast as possible (ie. non blocking). So what should we return as result if we are not yet able to generate it? The response is a promise of result!" So how am I supposed to use the same database transaction in a separate thread, or actor?